# Matching edges?

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges

I'm a complete beginner with Blender, and was wondering if its possible to do this:

I've got two meshes that are matching in terms of structure/wireframe, except the edges are misaligned. Any input on how I could match those edges without retopologizing? as it's important not change the vertex count or do any subdivisions (it's for Daz3D). [image: edges]

Comment: Making less edges without changing the vertex count to something smaller will leave you with curved polygons. Why do you need to keep the vertex count high? It seems like the thin “cut mark” as it were has WAY too many edges, and could easily be simplified.

Comment: The mesh is meant to be a high-subdivision morph for another software (daz3d), won't let me import it back in if I modify the vertex count or alter the structure in any way.

Comment: Well, that kind of says it in stone. If you can’t change the vertex count, than dissolving the edges won’t really have any effect in the long run because the render engine will just be interpolating new edges to triangulate it anyway. I recommend asking a new question for how to alter your trans-software procedure.

Comment: If they already have the correct scale but are only misaligned, you can enable snapping and then merge vertices by distance. If the two edge loops don't have identical scale but the top part also shouldn't be scaled, then you could connect both parts and then try to relax the area in between with loop tools. If you can scale the top part, you can both scale, try to snap and then remove the duplicate vertices. Could you tell which of the approaches you intend to go for, then we can write a proper answer?